# How to find Eigenvalue with Characteristic Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

When my book explains using the characteristic equation to find eigenvalues, it gives this example.

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
A = 
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$|\lambda I - A| =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda - 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda - 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

= $(\lambda - 2)^3$

It doesn't show any work for as how it got to $(\lambda - 2)^3$. Can someone fill me in to how the book gets this result? (using quadratic equation?)

Comment: Also note that in $\lambda I-A$ the entry $(1,2)$ should be $-1$, not $1$

Comment: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $\lambda I-A$ is upper triangular, so the determinant is the product of the entries on the diagonal.

Anyway, you should be able to compute the determinant of a generic matrix, even when it isn't triangular.

Comment: So in a non-triangular matrix, you just compute the determinant of the matrix and that will give you the roots?

Comment: You compute the determinant of $\lambda I-A$ and that will give you the characteristic polynomial $P_A(\lambda)$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of $P_A$.

Comment: @Evan Yes, it is a determinant. You wrote wrongly the matrix instead, it seems that it was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**A fast approach hint :** The matrix given is in upper triangular form, thus the determinant is simply the product of the diagonal elements. Thus :

$$|\lambda I - A | = \prod_{n=1}^3 \text{diag}_i(\lambda I-A) = (\lambda-2)^3$$

If you miss on that, calculate it the explicit way, by :

$$|\lambda I - A| =
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda - 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda - 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda - 2 \\
\end{vmatrix} = (λ-2)\cdot\begin{vmatrix}λ-2 & 0 \\ 0 & λ-2\end{vmatrix} + 1\cdot \begin{vmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & λ-2\end{vmatrix} + 0 \cdot \begin{vmatrix} 0 & λ-2 \\ 0 & 0\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$|\lambda I - A| = (λ-2) \cdot (λ-2)^2 + 0 + 0 = (λ-2)^3$$

The eigenvalues then, would simply be :

$$|\lambda I - A| = 0 \Rightarrow (\lambda-2)^3 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = 2, \; \text{with multiplicity of 3}$$

Comment: Would a valid strategy to find eigenvalues be to convert a non-triangular matrix into a triangular matrix to make finding the determinant easier?

Comment: @EvanKim Well, that really depends on the given problem. If, for example, you have a $4 \times 4$ or bigger dimension matrix, then if it's properly fixed so that it can be converted to upper triangular, it may be an easier way out then determinants since it takes a lot of time to calculate them explicitly. Other than that, on $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ matrices, the procedure to calculate the determinant is really fast anyway, so it wouldn't make much difference, except in the case that the given matrix is already in upper or lower triangular form (like your case).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your matrix is special. it makes the computation easier.

Assume $k\ne 2$ is an other eigenvalue. then there will exist $x,y,z$ satisfying
$$(x,y,z)\ne (0,0,0)$$
and
$$2x+y=kx$$
$$2y=ky$$
$$2z=kz$$
but
$$k\ne 2\implies z=y=x=0$$

which is in contradiction with the assumption.